# Python datetime does not sync with system time

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-datetime

i'd like to know how to sync datetime with system time in real time. what i mean is the code always prints the same hour same minute and same seconds if i loop the code. this is my code

```
from datetime import datetime
import os
from time import sleep


def clear():
    os.system('cls')

now = datetime.now()
current_time = now.strftime("%H:%M:%S")

while True:
    time = print("Current Time =", current_time)
    sleep(1)
    clear()
```

i need help for this thx!

[image: The image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are currently creating the date-time object only once with the line. This means the time is only looked up once and then that value is stored in the variable.

```
now = datetime.now()
current_time = now.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
```

All you need to do is move those two lines *into* your loop. That way, the time is looked up on each loop iteration and you get new values. The modified code:

```
from datetime import datetime
import os
from time import sleep


def clear():
    os.system('cls')

while True:
    now = datetime.now()
    current_time = now.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
    time = print("Current Time =", current_time)
    sleep(1)
    clear()
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answer! i also modify the code a little bit to make it a little bit better

```
from datetime import datetime
from time import sleep


while True:
     now=datetime.now()
     current_time=now.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
     time=print("Current Time : ", current_time, end=\r)
     sleep(1)
```